# How to setup access to webmin with ubuntu and apache2

Tags: apache, authentication, ubuntu, apache2, webmin

One of the directions say that /etc/webmin/htusers must match the users in /etc/webmin/webmin.acl

Although after finishing installation, htusers file didn't exist... so I created it. Now I don't know what needs to go in that file, or in what format.

My webmin.acl file contains one line starting with "root:"

I'm able to browse to the webmin site, just unable to authenticate.

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try `htpasswd -m hgusers username`, that should do it.